# Dymo barcode print error 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: bitmapStream'

Tags: vb.net, sdk, dymo

I am using the DYMO .net SDK for my VB.NET application. When I try to print a label with a barcode where the barcode value is too big to fit in the barcode, I get the following exception:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: bitmapStream

How can I check the size of a label object on the label template to see if the value will fit? It seems like sometimes it will correctly show ‘Barcode will not fit’ text but other times I get this error. When testing, I could try to print a label with 33 characters in the barcode, then remove a char and try again, and it would print fine.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in the following scenarios:

- Setting too much barcode data, exceeding the total free space on the label
- Trying to set EAN8 or EAN13 data including the Check Digit (you should not add the last digit in this case)